# Apex Test - Constructor Not Defined

Tags: apex, unit-test, constructor

Hi I'm having some issues with a test class which is calling a non-static method. I have looked at some previously asked question but I don't fully understand how to structure the calling of the class. I've attempted to create a new instance of the apex class and call the method from there but I then get the 'Constructor not defined: [myActualClass].()' error.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

```java
public with sharing class myActualClass{

    //Constructor
    public myActualClass( ApexPages.StandardSetController controller ) {
        
        this.RecordIDs = new List<String>();
        List<sObject> selectedRecords = (List<sObject>)controller.getSelected();
        for(sObject selectedRecord : selectedRecords){
            this.RecordIDs.add(selectedRecord.Id);
        }
    }    

    public void createPIN(){
           //Loop over this.RecordIDs
           //doSomething
    }
}
```

Separate Test Class Method

```java
    @isTest static void createPIN_TEST(){        
        Test.startTest();
        myActualClass newInstance = new myActualClass();
        newInstance.createPIN();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: Is it deployed to the org?

Comment: Yes both classes are in a Sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor is just a special method. If you specify parameter(s) for the constructor, as you have done, then you need to provide that as an "argument" when you call the constructor.

In this case, you need to create an instance of `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, and pass that into your constructor for `myActualClass`. The StandardSetController constructor itself requires a querylocator or a list of SObjects for its constructors.

At the bare minimum, your test method would look something like

```
@isTest
static void myTest(){
    // In a test class, you are responsible for setting up all of 
    //   the data your code needs to run
    Account testAcc = new Account(
        // If your code doesn't execute any queries for (or using) this Id, then
        //   you can simply fake the Id
        Id = '001' + '000000000000'
    );

    // Need a list to pass into the standard set controller
    List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>{testAcc};
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(acctList);

    // Finally, you can make the instance of your class
    MyActualClass myInstance = new MyActualClass(setCon);

    // Don't forget to make assertions!
    // They are the most important part of a unit test
}
```

That example is not meant to be simply copy/pasted. You will need to modify it to suit your needs. One specific thing I'll mention is that you'll need to call `setSelected()` before creating an instance of your actual class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm no longer getting the issue and my constructor class is now covered however I still don't understand how I would call the 'createPIN' non static class from the test class. EDIT - Apologies I've just seen your comment below the code. I'll try using the setSelected()

Comment: @plateaued1 `createPIN()` is an _instance method_ (as opposed to a static method), not a class. You call it the same way as you would call any other instance method (i.e. using dot notation on an _instance_ of the class that contains that method, the instance that you construct in your test method). Your example code, `newInstance.createPIN();` is correct, assuming that the code you've provided is a faithful reproduction of your actual code.

Comment: Thank you again, I've managed to get the start of the instance method covered however it's failing to loop over the 'RecordIDs' list that I have provided to the standardSetController, do I need to somehow pass this list when running the test?

Comment: @plateaued1 You should ask a new question for that (this one was strictly for the issue with the constructor). You'll also need to show some additional code. About the only other thing I can say right now is that you should read the final sentence of my answer again. `getSelected()` isn't going to return any data if you don't first select some data.

Comment: Thank you I've asked a another question around the setSelected() - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400107/apex-test-setselected-is-empty