# Apex Test - setSelected() is empty!

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, constructor

Hi I'm having an issue with a non-static test method which is passed a list of records from the standardSetController. I've called setSelected() and an instance of the non-static method but when I'm running the test and looking at coverage, the testing is stopping at the point when the method uses the list passed from setSelected().

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

```
public with sharing class myActualClass{

//Constructor
public myActualClass( ApexPages.StandardSetController controller ) {
    
    this.RecordIDs = new List<String>();
    List<sObject> selectedRecords = (List<sObject>)controller.getSelected();
    for(sObject selectedRecord : selectedRecords){
        this.RecordIDs.add(selectedRecord.Id);
    }
}    

public void createPIN(){
       for(String RecordID : this.RecordIDs){ //<This is where the coverage stops
           //doSomething
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest static void createPIN_TEST(){        
    Test.startTest();
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(RecordIDs);
    myActualClass myInstance = new myActualClass(setCon);
    setCon.setSelected(RecordIDs);
    myInstance.createPIN();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your constructor before you set the selected records. Therefore, no records are selected.

```
@isTest static void createPIN_TEST(){        
    Test.startTest();
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(RecordIDs);
    // This must happen first.
    setCon.setSelected(RecordIDs);
    myActualClass myInstance = new myActualClass(setCon);
    myInstance.createPIN();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's working perfectly now!